# Single Post (CPT) in two pages - Normal and Extended

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, urls, query-variable

How can I make a post (Post_type) have an extended view in a different page?

What I want to do is the same thing that this site does with "read more" and the URL of the post.

**A working example would be**
[Example](http://www.liquidagency.com/work/lumileds-shaping-the-future-of-light/)

Example normal post url:

```
http://domain.com/category/sample-post
```

Example full post url

```
http://domain.com/category/sample-post/?full=1
```

> site.com/category/simple-post -----> normal content post
>
> site.com/category/simple-post/?full=1  -----> full (different) content post

Please help, I have searched for many methods but none works for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is done right in the post editor, you can use the button that is second in from the right side, of the editor toolbar, to insert a read more link at a certain point in your post. Wordpress will display a shortened post with a read more link when the post is being viewed in a list of other posts in some category, for example. When you click on the more link, you are viewing that single post, and Wordpress displays the full post content.

I'd definitely recommend reading this codex entry:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#The_Excerpt_Basics

If this doesn't work as described, please provide more code/info for debugging, or clarify further if this doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: I understand perfectly what you say to me, but what I try to do goes beyond that. Let me explain you:

The post is separated into two contents (that I can do with ACF). The first one is displayed as **site.com/simple-post**. But, for example, if you press Read more, it takes you to another page with the same url of the post but adds a /?full=1,**(site.com/simple-post/?full=1)** in which it is shown Content.

I tried to think it could be done with rewrite endpoint, but no.

I hope you can understand me, thank you very much for your previous reply as well.